# Parse lines into individual segments - python

Tags: python

I'm new to python and having issues working with a text file. The text file structure being used is shown. What I'm trying to do is first split the two polylines into their own variable and then split each variable into individual coordinates. The end goal is to have it structured as:

```
polyline 1:
[###, ###] [###, ###]

polyline 2:
[###, ###] [###, ###]
```

Text file structure:

```
Polyline;

1: ###,###; ###,###

2: ###,###; ###,###; ###,###
```

The code I've tried is just working with a single line. While I've been able to split the single line, I have not been able to move to the next step which is to split the line further.

```
    f=open('txt.txt', 'r')
    pl = []
    for line in f.read().split('\n'):
        if (line.find('1: ') !=-1):
            ln = line.split('1: ')
            print ln
    f.close()
```

What is the best way to split the line to the end state?

Comment: try `ln.split(',')` ...

Comment: `for line in f.read().split('\n'):` -> `for line in f:`

Comment: How comes your second line ends up with 6 segments?

Comment: @tobias_k, actually the question should be how come he has 4 segments in the output (because the code block with 6 segments is actually a sample starting point).

Comment: @Kay: Technically, the `split` call will remove the newlines (though `.splitlines()` would do it better), so to make it equivalent, it would be `for line in f: line = line.rstrip('\n') ...`.

Answer (score 3):

First of all you can use `with ... as` statement to open a file which will close the file at the end of block , secondly you don't have to read the file and split with `\n` just use a for loop to loop over your file object.

Also for checking the start with digit number you can us regex and in this case you can use `re.match` function, then you can split the line with `;` and using a list comprehension split another parts with `,`  :

```
import re
with open('txt.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        if re.match(r'\d:.*',line):
            ln = [var.split(',') for var in line.split(';')]
            print ln
```